# Link errors when building shared library even though source files are included

Tags: dll, cmake, linker

I am specifying a shared library build from source files in my CMakeLists.txt file like so:

```
# Library setup
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/*.h)
```

Inside the source directories contain all my .h and .cpp files required to build my shared library. So I then do something like this:

```
add_library(mylibrary SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} )
```

I also link a bunch of other .libs with mylibrary later on as well (Could there be a clashing issue?). The problem arises when I try to build mylibrary. I receive  linking errors such as:

```
Severity    Code    Description                         Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_cosf   mylibrary    ***.obj    1
```

even though the symbol is defined  in my source files that I have included. I am not exactly sure what to do in order to properly let my project find those symbols. The funny thing is is that when I build as a static library it is fine. However, when I try to build as a dynamic library, these errors appear.

Comment: The best thing would be if you could provide a minimal example that reproduces this error. It would also of help if you could show us the messages from the "Output window" and not only form the "Error window" - I guess you are using VS

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not exactly sure why this worked. But there was a conflict warning between linking to MSVRCT and libcmt. It said something like this in the output log:

```
Resolving LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with ...
```

This is because libcmt is a static library for release build and uses \MT flags. MSVRCT is a release DLL version and compiled with \MD flag. Because of this conflict, I had to change my compiler flags to be:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
```

Then the symbols were able to be found. If anyone has any comments/corrections to why this worked please add.

Comment: It seems that my hint - look at the "Output window" - has helped you ;)

Comment: /MTd is the Debug version of the UCRT for static linking. /MT non-debug version - more details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx